# Frame origin is different from the one set

Tags: ios, swift

In the viewWillLayoutSubviews I set view's frame y origin to UIScreen.main.bounds.height, which means that the view should not be visible since it's below everything (I do call the super.viewWillLayoutSubviews on top of everything).

In the view hierarchy inspector the view looks exactly as it is supposed to be, but on real device you can see lower how it looks, it can be seen on the bottom of the screen on a real device, even if the origin is the screen height.

[view hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1Dxu.png)

[real device view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pi0W.jpg)

My question is why is the custom view looking different on the real device.
Also what is causing this strange bug? Any feedback is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Edit: This visual bug happens on all the devices except for the iPhone X

Edit2: This is the code I'm using to set the view's frame

```
customView.frame.origin.x = 0
customView.frame.origin.y = UIScreen.main.bounds.height     
customView.frame.size.width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
customView.frame.size.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.72
```

Edit3: Found the bug, my bad I didn't post this code from the beginning, I never thought the bug could happen because of this.

```
    let imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: customView.frame.width, height: customView.frame.height))
    imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imgView.image = gradientImage
    customView.addSubview(imgView)
    customView.sendSubview(toBack: imgView)
```

The bug comes from this line:

```
imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

Changed this to:

```
imgView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
```

Very very sorry for not mentioning this from the beginning, my fault, I'd like to thank everyone for their help, also thanks to @matt for pointing out that this code should be in the viewDidLayoutSubviews().

Comment: are you using auto layout ?

Comment: not using it on this custom view

Comment: so post your code to let us analyse it, can be a bunch of things

Comment: Getting your edit about iPhone X, have a look on safeMargins...

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_relative_to_the_safe_area

Comment: Is the parent view using auto layout?

Comment: @NateBirkholz the parent view is the view controller's main view

Comment: @GIJOW I'm checking right now the safe margins, maybe that causes the problem

Comment: Looks like your custom view either is or contains a `UIImageView`, possibly with a `contentMode` set to `.aspectFill`. If that's the case, try setting that image view's `clipsToBounds` to `true` (or check the equivalent checkbox in Interface Builder). Image views with `contentMode`s set to `.aspectFill` can actually have their content spill out of the image view's bounds, so maybe that's what's happening here.

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler you are perfectly right, this was the bug, post it as an answer and I'll mark it as the accepted answer, thank you very much!

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler wow, you actually figured this out before I even posted the code about the image view, good job!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your custom view either is (or contains) a `UIImageView`, possibly with a `contentMode` set to `.aspectFill`. If that's the case, try setting that image view's `clipsToBounds` to true (or check the equivalent checkbox in Interface Builder).

Image views with `contentMode`s set to `.aspectFill` can actually have their content spill out of the image view's bounds, so that looks to be what's happening here.